BladewindUI with Alpine JS
sorry if this is silly to ask but i haven't found any solution to this question of mine. so the code below is i want the page to run something (in this case, just alert on change of select option). if it was normal html, it'll be something like this
<select name="year" @change="alert('dd')">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

but when i used it on bladewind, it doesn't work. it seems to work on some(input) and not on others(toggle)
<x-bladewind::select @change="alert('dd')" name="year" searchable="true" label="Year" :data="$year" />

hence, is it my code that is wrong or some alpine js code is not applicable to bladewind ui? i'm using bladewind ui because i want to use its searchable select features instead of using select2 but at this rate, i think i have to use select2 back

The BladeWindUI Select is not compatible with AlpineJS as unexpected attributes such as @change are ignored.
A possible solution is to use the onselect attribute managed by the BladeWindUI Select to set an handler which can send a custom event passing the year as a parameter, then intercept the event on the Alpine side and extract the data - or in any case trigger any desired action:
<div x-data="{year: ''}"
     @set-year.window="year=$event.detail.year; alert('dd')"
>
   <x-bladewind::select name="year"
                        searchable="true"
                        label="Year"
                        :data="$year"
                        onselect="setAlpineYear"
   />

   <div x-text="`Selected year: ${year}`"> </div>

</div>

<script>
    const setAlpineYear = (value) => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("set-year", {detail: {year: value} }));
    }
</script>


i've tested and it works. but then i bump into another: my select has no response when i used it with livewire. turns out i missed it that it will be added according to their roadmap  (i've tested with input and it works, so probably some element are yet to be implemented). guess i'll be using tailwind for now
